# How to analyze the following ODE with 2 variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

THE ODEs has the following form:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dt} &= - \lambda xy\\
\frac{dx}{dt} &= -\eta y^2,
\end{align*}
where $\lambda$ and $\eta$ are constants. $y(0) = C_1 >0$ and $x(0) = C_2 >0$.

Is there any standard tool to analyze it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can deduce that:
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {\lambda x}{\eta y}$$
$$\eta y^2 -\lambda x^2=C$$

Comment: Therefore integral curves are conics...

Comment: @JeanMarie  Yes thats exact.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ and $y$ only depend on $t$ i think you could just have

$$y=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{1}{\eta}}$$

and substitute it into the first equation.